# Android :: created custom lock slider but on clicking home button, home screen appears

Tags: android

How to override click for Home button or how to disable homebutton?

Answer (score 0):

We cant override Home button same as back button.. but we can create HomeScreen Application and open our Home Screen Application on Home Button.

**Note: We Can't Override Home Button**

Comment: Then what is the principle behind lockscreen 7and wp7locklite  in android market

Comment: Read my answer carefully .. we can't override home button like as Back button but we can create HomeScreen Application

Comment: please check  lockscreen 7 and wp7 locklite in android market, this application is not asking to set as homescreen application.